# How to find if value reaches zero in a continuos function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object in three.js (don't think this is relevant though) which can accelerate when pressing a button. That object should stop on its own due to friction if I stop pressing the button.

What I'm doing is reducing the acceleration of an object (subtracting from it), and if it reaches zero velocity it should stop in place and not start moving in the opposite direction.

I'm trying if (velocity == 0) but that doesn't work because it just passes from 0.0001 to -0.001.

Is there a way to know whether a value has passed zero in a continuous function, or a better way to program this problem?

Comment: `(x+speedx)*x <= 0` ?

Answer (score 1):

How about `if (velocity <= 0) {}`?

Comment: why not `<= 0`?

Comment: Because it also has to be able to move backwards if you click the backwards button

Answer (score 0):

Since they are two seperate events, you will need to set a variable to indicate the state that the car is currently in.

```
velocityFunc(velocity, state = 'forward'){
    let speed = Math.sign(velocity)
    if (speed !== 1 || speed === 0 && state === 'forward'){
        return false 
    }

    if (speed !== -1 || speed === 0 && state === 'reverse'){
        return false 
    }
    return true
}
```

Then use the function like this:

```
if(!velocityFunc(velocity)){
   //the car was moving forward (with decelerating velocity) but it should now stop, it has crossed the foward threshold
}
```

or

```
if(!velocityFunc(velocity, 'reverse')){
    //the car was reversing (with decelerating velocity) but it should now stop, it has crossed the reverse threshold
}
```

> This way, if:
>
> - The car is decelerating (while moving foward) and it reaches 0, and moves on to a - (negative speed | starts moving backwards), it will be
>     forced to stop.
> - If the car is decelerating (while in reverse), and it reaches 0, and starts moving foward (accelerating with positive velocity), it
>     will also be forced to stop.

**NB:** *The above code is untested but should work.*

Comment: That doesn't work for the other way around, if the function is coming from the negatives and passes 0

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to check the before and after values during the subtraction operation. A good way to do this is to compare their [`Math.sign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign) values.

```
const beforeSign = Math.sign(velocity);
// Code to update velocity
const afterSign = Math.sign(velocity);
if( beforeSign !== afterSign ) {
  // Do code for stopping
}
```

I noticed how other answers did not specifically address your issue:

> If it reaches (I assume "crosses") zero velocity it should stop in place and not start moving in the opposite direction.